# Python Plotting a shapefile on a basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I am using python 3.6 to plot a shapefile containing large watersheds in the U.S. The problem that I am running into is that this shapefile has many components, such as a .dbf file, a .prj file... and others. I am not sure if I have to read all the files in individually and then plot or if there is one command that will allow me to read them all at once and then plot.

Here is my code so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydbf =('filename.dbf')
myprj =('filename.prj')
myqpj =('filename.qpj')
myshp =('filename.shp')
myshx =('filename.shx')


map= Basemap(projection='cyl',
            lon_0=180,
            lat_0=0,
            resolution='l')
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

map.readshapefile(mydbf,myprj,myqpj,myshp,myshx,'Watersheds')
plt.show()
```

The error message I am getting when I run this code is:
`OSError: cannot locate filename.dbf.shp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [basemap tutorial](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html) on readthedocs it clearly says about the `readshapefile` function

> The first parameter shapefile name must go without the shp extension. The library assumes that all shp, sbf and shx files will exist with this given name

Your call should therefore be

```
map.readshapefile("filename",'Watersheds')
```

Comment: I understand that but that will only work for one. All of the files are named the exact same so without adding the .shp or .dbf it is only plotting one file.

Comment: Yes, you have one shapefile `filename.shp` with its auxilary files `filename.sbf` and `filename.shx`. If you have a second one, that would be  `filename2.shp` with its auxilary files `filename2.sbf` and `filename2.shx` and you would repeat the reading like `map.readshapefile("filename2",'Watersheds2')`.